# Can i used non static variable in static method in apex?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have reached a dead end while trying to solve an issue with my application. I am having trouble in using a non-static variable in a static method. Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

below is my static method

```
public static List<Client_Payment__c> fetchClientPayment(String billId, String clientId){
    Client_Payment__c clientPayment = new Client_Payment__c();
    clientPayment.Client__c = clientId;
    clientPayment.Bill__c = billId;           
    clientPayment.Tills__c = globTill ;  // This is a static variable I've to used 
    insert clientPayment;
    return null;
}
```

below is my method that set static variable

```
public PageReference  afFillTill(){
    globTill = strHiddenTill;
    System.debug('myString: ' + strHiddenTill);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-static variables and methods are associated with an instance of class. You can only use non-static variables inside non-static methods. If you want use common variables in static and non-static method declare variable as **static**. Refer for more clarification on [static variables](http://www.sfdc99.com/2015/01/22/introduction-to-the-static-keyword/).